# numpy.argsort function returning ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

I am creating a function that sorts data using numpy.argsort. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

## 1. Complete sort_data

def sort_data(data):
    
    """ (tuple) -> tuple
    
    data is a tuple of two lists.
    
    Returns a copy of the input tuple sorted in
    non-decreasing order with respect to the 
    data[0]
    
    >>> sort_data(([5, 1, 7], [1, 2, 3]))
    ([1, 5, 7], [2, 1, 3])

    >>> sort_data(([2, 4, 8], [1, 2, 3]))
    ([2, 4, 8], [1, 2, 3])

    >>> sort_data( ([11, 4, -5], [1, 2, 3]))
    ([-5, 4, 11], [3, 2, 1])
    """
    ([x], [y]) = data
    
    xarray = np.array(x)
    yarray = np.array(y)
    
    xx = np.argsort(xarray)
    yy = np.argsort(yarray)
    
    xsort = xarray[xx]
    ysort = yarray[yy]
    
    
    return ([xsort],[ysort])
```

The docstring returns:

```
line 37, in sort_data
        ([x], [y]) = data
    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

I think this is because of the function taking the tuple data with the two lists inside, but I am unsure of how to fix this problem. How do I get it to return correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Unpacking to 2 variables works fine:

```
In [42]: data = ([5, 1, 7], [1, 2, 3])
In [43]: x,y=data
In [44]: x
Out[44]: [5, 1, 7]
In [45]: (x,y)=data
In [46]: y
Out[46]: [1, 2, 3]
```

But your try:

```
In [47]: ([x],[y])=data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-47-9f88af1e8960>", line 1, in <module>
    ([x],[y])=data
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

corrected:

```
In [48]: ([x,y,z],w)=data
In [49]: x
Out[49]: 5
```

It can't unpack `[5,1,7]` into `[x]`.

Other expressions that produce that error:

```
In [50]: [x]=[5,1,7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-50-18b1033808bd>", line 1, in <module>
    [x]=[5,1,7]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

In [51]: x,=[5,1,7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-51-da60f4d5d887>", line 1, in <module>
    x,=[5,1,7]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Comment: My data has to be a tuple with two lists, x and y, though for my assignment, I am still confused on how to do this while keeping data as the tuple with lists. I tried to do : ([x],[y]) = data
    [a,b,c] = x
    [d,e,f] = y but it still did not work

Comment: Do you want `x` and `y` to be lists, or single numbers from those lists?  Didn't my example show that you should not be using `[x]`?

Comment: x and y need to be lists yes, not single numbers from the list